# How to bind nested objects on HttpPost in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have started to implement this solution [bind attribute include and exclude property with complex type nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892550/bind-attribute-include-and-exclude-property-with-complex-type-nested-objects)

but it does not work at all.

The same question is here [Binding nested model with MVC3 on HttpPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545515/binding-nested-model-with-mvc3-on-httppost)

but no concrete answer.

Model

```
[Bind(Include = "FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Position,TruckTypeID,Direction,Organization,Objective,TimeStart,TimeEnd")]
public partial class UserRequestRegisterModel
{
    [DisplayName("Имя")]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Фамилия")]
    [Required]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Отчество")]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Должность")]
    [Required]
    public string Position { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Тип транспорта")]
    [Required]
    public System.Guid TruckTypeID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Направление")]
    [Required]
    public string Direction { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Организация")]
    [Required]
    public string Organization { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Цель")]
    [Required]
    public string Objective { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Время убытия")]
    [Required]
    // [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public System.DateTime TimeStart { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Время прибытия")]
    [Required]
    // [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeEnd { get; set; }        
}


[Bind(Include = "UserRequest")]
public partial class RequestUserModel
{
    public List<UserRequestViewItem> UserRequestViewItems { get; set; }
    public UserRequestRegisterModel UserRequest { get; set; }

    public RequestUserModel()
    {
        UserRequestViewItems = new List<UserRequestViewItem>();
        UserRequest = new UserRequestRegisterModel();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Position,TruckTypeID,Direction,Organization,Objective,TimeStart,TimeEnd")] RequestUserModel userRequest)
//public ActionResult Index(RequestUserModel userRequest)
{
    // !  userRequest.UserRequest is empty  !
    //...
}
```

Comment: Your editing data so ALWAYS use a view model and you never need an awful `[Bind]` attribute when using a view model

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, bro! Please help with some working solution.

Comment: _but it does not work at all._ - What  does not work? What are you wanting to achieve? Just create view models that represent what you want in the view and get rid of your `[Bind]` attributes - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke `userRequest.UserRequest` on HttpPost should have inputed values but they are empty.

Comment: Because the `[Bind]` attribute in your POST method states - _include only the properties named `"FirstName", "MiddleName"`, etc_, and your `RequestUserModel` does not contain any properties with those names (only the `UserRequest` property contains those names). Again, use a view model!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok, but what do I have to do then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160470/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-academy-of-programmer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 30 minutes of freestyle experimenting I finally get it working.

So, guys, solution is following

**Model**

```
 [Bind(Include = "FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Position,TruckTypeID,Direction,Organization,Objective,TimeStart,TimeEnd")]
    public partial class UserRequestRegisterModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Имя")]
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Фамилия")]
        [Required]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Отчество")]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Должность")]
        [Required]
        public string Position { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Тип транспорта")]
        [Required]
        public System.Guid TruckTypeID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Направление")]
        [Required]
        public string Direction { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Организация")]
        [Required]
        public string Organization { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Цель")]
        [Required]
        public string Objective { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Время убытия")]
        [Required]
        // [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public System.DateTime TimeStart { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Время прибытия")]
        [Required]
        // [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeEnd { get; set; }        
    }


public partial class RequestUserModel
    {
        public List<UserRequestViewItem> UserRequestViewItems { get; set; }
        public UserRequestRegisterModel UserRequest { get; set; }

        public RequestUserModel()
        {
            UserRequestViewItems = new List<UserRequestViewItem>();
            UserRequest = new UserRequestRegisterModel();
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
@model TransportRequests.Models.RequestUserModel
...

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateUserRequest", null, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserRequest.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px" } })
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateUserRequest([Bind(Include = "UserRequest")] RequestUserModel model)
{
     // and here all properties has inputed values... YEAH!!!  :)

     var firstName = model.UserRequest.FirstName;

     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Interesting, still I'm with @StephenMuecke, the usage of the `BindAttribute` is awful and this code is a perfect example why you should get rid of it